# How to copy Diagnostic Setting from one resource to another in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I want to use PowerShell to copy a configuration setting from one resource (SQL database) to another database. I have the following code so far.

```
$sourceResource = Get-AzResource -Name aaa-bbb-ccc-sql/TemplateJob
Write-Output "Source Resource ID: " $sourceResource.Id

$sourceResourceId = $sourceResource.id
Write-Output "Source Resource ID: " $sourceResourceId
$diagnosticSetting = Get-AzDiagnosticSetting -resourceid $sourceResourceId

$targetResource = Get-AzResource -Name aaa-bbb-ccc-sql/Test4
Write-Output "Target Resource ID: " $targetResource.Id
$targetResourceId = $targetResource.id
Write-Output "Target Resource ID: " $targetResourceId

Set-AzDiagnosticSetting -Name $diagnosticSetting.Name -ResourceId $targetResourceId
```

I keep getting all kind of errors from the last line. Help anybody. Appreciated in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would use first Export of Resource Manager template:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/export-template-powershell

and then just deploy it with new parameters and target.
Or just use this template with params: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/resource-manager-diagnostic-settings#diagnostic-setting-for-azure-sql-database

PS: next time please put some errors as well, hard to determine what issue you have :)